# Java 1.3 String.replaceAll() , replacement

Tags: java, regex

I'm working with some really old `Java. 1.3` to be exact.

I'm attempting to sanitize some `String` input by removing non alphabet characters (punctuation and numbers, etc)

Normally I'd do something like:

```
String.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
```

However, `.replaceAll()` was introduced in `Java 1.4`! So it won't compile! [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

How did we accomplish this prior to `Java 1.4`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis haha! yes, not fun to maintain this particular codebase... *sigh* - i think 1.3 was circa 2000?

Comment: You may look at replaceAll() in latest source and try to replicate that in 1.3

Comment: @Nambari hmm, a possibility. Although, if it's like the other String methods, it uses a lot of internal vars from within the String object. -- even if I could, it feels "dirty" to do it that way. Surely Java Devs in the early 2000's had a need to replace chars in Strings easily?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I have started my career with Java 1.2, so there are few.

Comment: @Nambari, if so, then they must be too old ;)

Comment: Refer to String API docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/String.html.   pay special attention to the indexOf() and substring() methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Java 1.3 exists. I'm alive. So yes ;). I think a better question would be: "Was anyone on stackoverflow even alive before Java 1.4 existed?"

Comment: Stripped of my trusty `replaceAll()` method, were it me, I would iterate over a `toCharArray()` version of the `String` and build a new string, skipping any characters that fall outside of the alphabet range

Comment: @StormeHawke this is likely faster than the regular expression replaceAll actually. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Noting that you can freely reference chars as ints and test whether they're in the range of ascii codes represented by [A-Za-z].  This works for ASCII... I'm probably presuming a lot by that

Comment: Or start from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char)

Comment: @Cruncher I think somebody grabbed my idea already.  No worries, question's been answered

Comment: Java 1.1 for me. But Java 1.3 is so old, it didn't even get an End Of Life date, Java 1.4 was EOL 5 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well probably you can write a simple loop like this:

```
char[] origArr = str.toCharArray();
char[] destArr = new char[origArr.length];
int j = 0;
for (int i=0; i < origArr.length; i++) {
    char c = origArr[i];
    if ((c >= 65 && c <= 90) || (c >= 97 && c <= 122))
       destArr[j++] = c;
}

String dest = new String(destArr, 0, j);
```

Sorry don't have JDK1.3 to test it out.

Comment: This is what I would do. However, probably change the final constructor to `String dest = new String(destArr, 0, j)` to make sure `dest` isn't doing anything with those extra Array elements.

Comment: @quazzieclodo: Yes I thought about it but wasn't sure if that constructor was available in JDK 1.3 but yes it is available then **`String dest = new String(destArr, 0, j);`** should be used in the end.

Comment: by the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char[],%20int,%20int%29), it has been around since the start. (At least there's no "Since:" section)

Comment: @quazzieclodo: Many thanks for looking over the docs. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

See if this works:

```
public static String replaceAll(
    String haystack,              // String to search in
    String needle,                // Substring to find
    String replacement) {         // Substring to replace with

    int i = haystack.lastIndexOf( needle );
    if ( i != -1 ) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer( haystack );
        buffer.replace( i, i+needle.length(), replacement );
        while( (i=haystack.lastIndexOf(needle, i-1)) != -1 ) {
            buffer.replace( i, i+needle.length(), replacement );
        }
        haystack = buffer.toString();
    }

    return haystack;
}
```

EDIT: This won't support regular expressions. As you're looking to erase more than just a single character, I would suggest you either tweak this code to allow an array of `needles` or (the ugly method) loop through the disallowed characters and repeatedly call the function.

Comment: Timer is still counting - but this compiled! I'm going to throw some data through it and see if the output ends up as expected (it should from what i see).

Comment: `lastIndexOf(String)` does not handle regular expressions, I believe. The Pattern class was not even in java until 1.4

Comment: @quazzieclodo: Though you are completely correct, I believe I beat you to the punch by about 21 seconds :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jakarta](http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/) by the Apache Software Foundation.

> Jakarta Regexp is a 100% Pure Java Regular Expression package

It's not maintained but the last version is not so old (2011).

The documentation: http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/

For the replaceAll you can use `subst` with the `REPLACE_ALL` flag.

PS: The link is dead, [here a mirror to download the lib](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjakartaregexp15jar.htm).

Comment: Are sure modern libs are 1.3-compatible? :-)

Comment: My **guess** is that this library **may** use `replaceAll` under the hood.

Comment: Not to mention at the top of the site it says it has been retired for over two years.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need only alphabets and anything else to be replaced with blank.
Character also got isDigit method. please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html if it helps.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{


String yourstring = "2323ABF!@CD24";
char[] check = yourstring.toCharArray();
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
for(int i=0; i < check.length; i++){
    if(!Character.isLetter(check[i])){
       str.append("");
    }
    else{
        str.append(check[i]);
    }
}
System.out.println(str.toString());
}
```

Comment: I believe this to be the best solution.